# How to get data form a OneNote table to a Outlook macro?

Tags: vba, outlook, onenote

I am working on a complex macro that will source data from many places and based on this data create a message and an appointment in Outlook. One of those places I need to take data from is a table placed inside a OneNote tab, that people put an email into. All I need is that email inside the Outlook macro so I can feed this into the e-mail being created. Seems easy, but...

So far I have not found an answer on SO or other places, that was clear enough for me to understand. I presume one would have to add OneNote in References, and thus gaining some VB command/commands/datasources that would do that, but I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to this. Can you advise, or at least point in the right direction?

(I use MS Office 365/Win10)

Comment: Can you try exporting the OneNote as HTML, then parsing the HTML to find the table?

Comment: @RyanWildry - nah... I need this to be seamless and working without user intervention. Unless this all be done by the code itself, which I understand you are suggesting. Still I do not know how to do that. A good thought though.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @fcsr Not really. Just pointing in the right direction would be enough. Provided this direction solves my problem.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).